# Fixed Element Overflow in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, fixed

[image]

Hello,

I have an header that its position is fixed. When I scroll the page, the paragraph below decreases its opacity. when the paragraph goes up, it overlays the header instead of "going under it". How can I fix it.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you give me the site url?. I think this is the 'z-index ' problem. try to set "z-index: 9999" to your header element.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it did not work. I did not upload the site to the internet

Answer (score 1):

Try adding z-index to your header.

```
z-index: 9999;
```

Header z-index should be more than you content's z-index.
hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I solved it. i wrapped all of the content below the haeder in a div. I gave the div a z-index of 1 and the header of 9999.